# Third stage of my In-memory Notebook - Golang

Tags: go, command-line-interface

"Enter a command and data: " - this prints twice instead of once and I'm unable to figure out why

The plan is "Enter the maximum number of notes: " prints to CLI, get and saves user input, then print "Enter a command and data: " prints. But it keeps printing twice on the same line.

Here is the code below.

```
 package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func readFromStdin() string {
    fmt.Print("Enter a command and data: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    line, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    //line = line[:len(line)-2]
    line = strings.TrimSpace(line)

    return line
}

func main() {
    var notes []string
    var maximumNotes int

    for {
        if maximumNotes <= 0 {
            fmt.Print("Enter the maximum number of notes: ")
            _, _ = fmt.Scan(&maximumNotes)
        }
        line := readFromStdin()
        var joinedNote string
        var note []string

        splittedString := strings.Split(line, " ")
        if splittedString[0] == "create" && len(notes) >= maximumNotes {
            fmt.Println("[Error] Notepad is full")
        }
        if splittedString[0] == "create" && len(splittedString) <= 1 {
            fmt.Println("[Error] Missing note argument")
        }
        if splittedString[0] == "create" && len(splittedString) > 1 && len(notes) < maximumNotes {
            i := 1
            for ; i < len(splittedString); i++ {
                note = append(note, splittedString[i])
            }
            joinedNote = strings.Join(note, " ")
            notes = append(notes, joinedNote)
            fmt.Println("[OK] The note was successfully created")
        }
        if splittedString[0] == "list" && len(notes) <= 0 {
            fmt.Println("[Info] Notepad is empty")
        }
        if splittedString[0] == "list" {
            for i, noteList := range notes {
                //newNote := strings.TrimSpace(noteList)
                fmt.Printf("[Info] %d: %s\n", i+1, noteList)
            }
        }
        if splittedString[0] == "clear" {
            notes = nil
            fmt.Println("[OK] All notes were successfully deleted")
        }

        if splittedString[0] == "exit" {
            fmt.Println("[Info] Bye!")
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are executing this on a Windows system.

I researched for this issue and found that there is an issue with
Windows system with bufio.ReadString

```
# '\n' will be added in the next reading function, if any
buf.ReadString('\r')

# you finish with the string that you want plus '\r' at the end
buf.ReadString('\n')
```

This is happening because EOL in Windows system is represented by `'\r\n'`

For more info on this https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/hWoESdeZ398

So in your case if we change the line `line, _ := reader.ReadString('\r')`

and I tried executing this on Windows and it solved your problem.